# ArcGIS metadata ISO 19115-1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, metadata

I need to implement ISO 19115-1 standards to a collection of datasets using ArcCatalog. However, I'm having trouble locating documentation about actually using the updated standard in Arc.

I've found [documentation for 10.5](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/metadata/support-for-iso-metadata-standards.htm)-- it states that previous 19115:2003 versions will be compatible with 19115-1, but does not provide documentation for a revised 19115-1 Metadata Style (This document is for 10.5, and I do not have access above 10.2).

Based on previous experience, I thought saving a new .cfg file in my C:/Arc/Metadata folder would be a solid workaround, but I can't locate the file anywhere.

Have any of you used ISO 19115-1, what do you suggest?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What do you mean about saving a new .cfg to your metadata folder?  I don't have 10.2 - is 19115-1 not an available metadata standard in 10.2?  Or is it avaialable and you're wanting to know how to use it?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with any response to comments

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! :)
In ArcCatalog, you can choose your metadata schema from a dropdown under 'Customization'>'ArcCatalog Options'. The metadata styles shown in this dropdown match the .cfg files saved in the program files Metadata folder (C:ProgramFiles/Arc/Metadata).  I thought I could find the ISO19115-1 .cfg file somewhere online and drop it in this location (this is just a hunch, and I can't locate this file).
I'm using Arc 10.2, but the most recent ISO is 19115:2003, and I need 19115-1. I think it's available in more recent versions but don't have access. Do you know?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with any response to comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running ArcGIS Desktop versions **10.3.1** and **10.5**, and neither of these have a `.cfg` file for ISO19115-1.

- ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1:
  [image]
- ArcGIS Desktop 10.5:
  [image]

The only time I've seen a metadata standard added to ArcGIS Desktop it was a full installer (from a third party) that installed more than just a `.cfg` file.  You might have luck contacting Esri directly, however I believe this is something you will possibly need to purchase from a third party.

Comment: Thanks so much for checking! Just knowing it's not in the more recent versions is still valuable info. I'll follow up with Esri to see if it's available for purchase.